# Can we use "keep bugging" with unanimated things or abstracts?

Tags: phrase-usage

The phrase "**keep bugging**" is usually used to describe "*when somebody is bothering or annoying someone*". But what if it's not somebody but something that does that?

- That idea I told you of keeps bugging me in my sleep.
- The sound of the generator keeps bugging me every night.
- This memory keeps constantly bugging me every day.

Can we use it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, inanimate objects and incorporeal ideas can "bug you".  The first and third examples you give sound great.

The second doesn't, though, because things don't "bug", they "bug something"; bug is a transitive verb.  You can say, "the sound of the generator keeps bugging me every night."

Comment: Sorry, the omission of "**me**" wasn't done on purpose.

Comment: Oh, in that case all three sound great. :)